# how to display product sku in custom admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, sku

hello everyone I want to display the product SKU in custom admin grid 
I have column displaying in it now I want to display the data of it

index.xml

```
<column name="sku"> 
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products sku</item> 
        </item> 
        </argument> 
        </column>
```

through this code column is displaying now i want to display the data of product sku any help will be appriacted